# Getting Notifications of isDocumentEdited

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nsundomanager

is it possible to bind/get notifications of the isDocumentEdited property of NSDocument without calling the will/didChangeValueForKey: methods on every change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `-updateChangeCount:` in your subclass so it posts an `NSNotification` or does whatever work you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I'll extend [Mike Abdullah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429862/39974):

To get bindings to work with `isDocumentEdited`, I implemented the following override on the `NSDocument` method:

```
- (void)updateChangeCount:(NSDocumentChangeType)change
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isDocumentEdited"];
    [super updateChangeCount:change];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isDocumentEdited"];
}
- (void)updateChangeCountWithToken:(id)changeCountToken forSaveOperation:(NSSaveOperationType)saveOperation
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isDocumentEdited"];
    [super updateChangeCountWithToken:changeCountToken forSaveOperation:saveOperation];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isDocumentEdited"];
}
```